# Custom UIViewController init with init related data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a question regarding the custom `init` methods specifically on `UIViewControllers`. Let's say that I write an `init` method which takes one parameter (let's say `UIViewControllerInitMode`) and that parameter is responsible to indicate in which way the view should load. So when the `viewDidLoad` gets called that parameter (now stored as a class variable) gets checked and the GUI related content is loaded accordingly. How is this done?

Let's take this example:

We have a `NS_ENUM` called `UIViewControllerInitMode` with modes `kUIViewControllerInitModeOne` and `kUIViewControllerInitModeTwo`. Now for the `init` and `viewDidLoad` code:

```
- (instancetype)initWithMode:(UIViewControllerInitMode)m
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
         mode = m; //Assume that mode is a class variable
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (mode == kUIViewControllerInitModeOne) //Check the class variable
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    else //It's the InitModeTwo
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Now this looks like a perfectly legitimate piece of code (at least to me) but if my knowledge is correct the actual view of a `UIViewController` gets lazy loaded so there is no telling if the view is blue or red when the class variable gets set (except with an extra if but that looks ugly because it would mean I have the same code for GUI in `init` and in `viewDidLoad`). So does this mean that under some circumstances the view can have a red background even if I `init`ed the controller with the mode that should make a blue background? Setting the background color in `init` is not safe for the same reason or is it? It always works if I do it in the way of the example above but I want to get to the bottom of this. How does this happen under the hood? Where am I right and/or wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no problem with the code above. You are right that you should not touch UI components in the `init` as they are most likely `null` at that time. The `initWithMode` method should not care what color the view is as it is probably no color at all. The `viewDidLoad` method is for changing the display properties of the view and other UI components. Due to the fact that the `init` will always be called before the `viewDidLoad`, your view should always be set to either red or blue based on `mode`.

Answer (score 0):

You example is perfectly fine. You can set the views properties after it is created. When you changes don't show up, you can ask the view to draw itself again by calling

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Setting the background color in init would fail, I guess, because the view isn't initialized in init yet. But I'm not sure about this. Just try it.

Comment: I am familiar with the `setNeedsDisplay` method but my question was strictly pointed at the: Is the view loaded after the whole subclassed `init` finishes or it loads at some point in time after the `[super init]` gets called and there is no telling if the class properties have already been set in `viewDidLoad` callback?